# Sequelize return all associations with where search

Tags: mysql, search, sequelize.js, where-clause

I have a song model and a tag model, both with a belongsToMany relationship, where there are multiple tags that can be associated with multiple songs. I'm preforming a findAll where I include an associated model with a search term, but the results of my search only includes that specific property, and not the rest of the properties that are associated with the model. Whereas when findAll is applied without the where I am given every associated tag.

```
const tracks = await Track.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Tag,
      where: { name: { [Op.substring]: `%${'favorite'}%` } },
    },
  ],
});
```

result:

```
...otherSongData,
Tags: [
    {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "#favorite",
        "track_tags": {
            "tag_id": 22,
            "track_id": 9
        }
    }
]
```

Instead of just this one tag coming back with my query I need ALL the tags to so that I can search for multiple tags at once and get all songs that have those tags.

I've tried to perform a search using:

```
const serachParams = [
  { name: { [Op.substring]: `%${'favorite'}%` } },
  { name: { [Op.substring]: `%${'guitar'}%` } },
]

...
  where: {
    [Op.and]: searchTerms,
  },
...
```

where I'd expect to get all songs with both guitar and favorite tags, but it seems like because where only returns that specific tag on my object any following searches will result in no results since all of the tags aren't being included in the result.

Comment: What DB you are using?

Comment: I'm using SQL, sorry should've put that in the description.

Comment: SQL is a language. DB is like PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB, etc and please add that as a tag.

Comment: Sorry,  it's MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For simple query, to search where any tags that includes **either** favorite **or** guitar, you can change your query to use `OR` with `like`.

```js
const serachParams = [
  { name: { [Op.like]: '%favorite%' } },
  { name: { [Op.like]: '%guitar%' } },
]

...
  where: {
    [Op.or]: searchTerms,
  },
...
```

For an advanced query, to find **both** favorite **and** guitar appears in **any order**. You can use `FULLTEXT` search.

For MySQL v5.6+, FULLTEXT search is supported for `InnoDB` engine. For MySQL <v5.6, it is supported for `MYISAM` but not `InnoDB`. You might need to change the engine if you are using a non-supported engine on your version.

To do `FULLTEXT` search, first turn on the FULLTEXT on a column.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD FULLTEXT(name);
```

Then, you can do query like

```
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+favorite +guitar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- This matches 
-- - favorite guitar
-- - guitar favorite
-- - favorite guitar something else
```

The "+" means that this word **has** to appear in `name`, so this query above will search `name` that includes both "favorite" and "guitar" (in any order)

If you do not add "+", this means this word is **optional** but ranked higher if exists.

```
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+favorite guitar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- This matches 
-- - favorite guitar  => if there is guitar, it appears at top
-- - guitar favorite
-- - favorite something else => If missing guitar, it still matches but appears at bottom
```

More about `FULLTEXT` search, refer https://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/

To put this in Sequelize,

```js
// Take out + according to your preference.
// These words should be space separated string
const searchParams = '+favorite +guitar';

...
where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('MATCH', Sequelize.col('name')), 
                       'AGAINST',
                       Sequelize.literal(`('${searchParams}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`))
...
```